# Maven cucumber reporting failure - Java.io.FilenotFound exception cucumber.json

Tags: java, maven-plugin, cucumber-jvm

I'm experiencing following error, on trying to run CucumberJVM tests using Maven Reporting Mojo.

[INFO] --- maven-cucumber-reporting:0.0.5:generate (execution) @ testproject ---
About to generate
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users//IdeaProjects/testproject/target/cucumber.json (No such file or directory)

I have following dependencies in POM.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.cucumber.reporting.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.reporting.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.totallylazy</groupId>
    <artifactId>totallylazy</artifactId>
    <version>1077</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
    <version>1.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Repositories set to following.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.bodar.com</id>
        <url>http://repo.bodar.com</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-releases</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Plugin set to following :

```
 <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.cucumber.reporting.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>${project.name}</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-html-reports</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                            <enableFlashCharts>false</enableFlashCharts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I'm using Standard maven project structure, with feature files hosted in /src/test/resources,  Step definitions under /src/test/main.

Would you please advise how to resolve this issue. I'm seeing this issue on MAC 64-bit OS.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Raja

Answer (score 2):

The plugin generates the HTML report from json.  So the first step is to have cucumber generate the json.

When I ran into the same issue I found the cause of this the problem is that the cucumber.json file does not exist.

I addressed this in my project by adding json:target under the `@CucumberOptions` annotation, this then generated the json.  for example

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/some.feature",
         monochrome = false, format = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json"})
```

The masterthought plugin then processes the generated JSON by looking for it at `${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json`

At this point the Maven plugin generates the HTML from the JSON.

Comment: This was failing for me (plugin instead of format). I had to create the target/cucumber.json file by hand to get it working. Hope this helps the next person.